# How do I prevent Babel from emitting export declarations twice?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, es6-modules

I was looking at the output of Babel (version 7.2.3, using `preset-env`) today on some JavaScript I'm building.  This code is going to be used exclusively in the browser, possibly over slow connections, and on preexisting websites, so I'm bending over backward to make the code as compact as possible.  Most of Babel's transpiling occurred the way I thought it should, but I was somewhat surprised at how much redundant code it emitted to support exports.

---

Specifically, I was surprised that this simple declaration —

```
export const foo = ... ,
    bar = ... ,
    baz = ... ;
```

gets transpiled to multiple sets of assignments —

```
exports.foo = exports.bar = exports.baz = void 0;

...

var foo = ... ,
    bar = ... ,
    baz = ... ;

...

exports.foo = foo;
exports.bar = bar;
exports.baz = baz;
```

when I was expecting something a bit lighter and more direct, like either of the two forms below:

*(expected, and acceptable)*

```
var foo = ... ,
    bar = ... ,
    baz = ... ;

exports.foo = foo;
exports.bar = bar;
exports.baz = baz;
```

*(ideal)*

```
exports.foo = ... ;
exports.bar = ... ;
exports.baz = ... ;
```

---

No matter what I've tried so far, I can't get Babel to emit anything shorter or simpler than the output shown above.  There don't seem to be configuration options (something like `--no-recursive-modules`), and there don't seem to be any changes I can make to the declarations to make Babel behave better either.  I'd still prefer to use the `export` keyword rather than writing an `exports` object directly, since `export` syntax is the future.

This module is otherwise tightly written, so it's mostly composed of small functions (and higher-order function invocations) that reference each other and that are nearly all exported — and that means that about a third of the resulting JS after minification consists of *just* `export` declarations!

Babel probably adds the initial `void 0` assignment to be careful about recursive module inclusion, or something, but none of that's happening in this module:  The imports and exports are strictly tree-shaped, not even DAG-shaped — and definitely not recursive or general-graph-like.  That `void 0` assignment is simply wasted code, wasted download time, and wasted execution time in the browser.

---

*tl;dr*:  To get the size of my Babel-transpiled module down to what it should be:

**How do I prevent Babel from emitting the useless `exports.foo = exports.bar = ... = void 0;` declaration at the top of the output?**

Comment: "*Babel probably adds the initial void 0 assignment to be careful about recursive module inclusion, or something*" - yes, probably it tries to emulate the hoisting of variables in the export object. However, I think you should file a bug (something like a feature request to "*optimise out export hoisting when not needed*") at the Babel project, not ask a StackOverflow question, to solve this.

Comment: I asked on SO because I figured somebody had already encountered this problem and already knew of some kind of obscure `--optimize-out-export-hoisting` flag. It would be disappointing if the only fix is "research, code up, and then submit a patch/plugin to the Babel team."

Comment: Agreed, there might be a workaround (obscure or not) and SO could answer the question, but I suspect asking the Babel team at Github will get you a better answer on this quite specific issue.

Comment: Given that the code is likely minified and gzipped in production, I'd expect this to make very little difference in the overall file size.

Comment: Yes, it is, but fixing this does actually make a difference. I was comparing the minified sizes when I said "a third of the code is exports." And if you're security-paranoid and have turned off Deflate compression to avoid the [CRIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME) and [BREACH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH) family of TLS attacks, you can't bet on gzip to save you. And even if you leave Deflate enabled, gzip is not a panacea: What's better than a good compression algorithm is not having bytes that need to be compressed in the first place.